# Passing parameters on named patterns via {% url %} in Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

On my template I have this

```
<a href="{% url 'call_donation' event=event.id %}" class="button" >Pitch in</a>
```

on views.py

```
def callDonation(request, event_id):
    donation = DonationOrder.create(event_id)
    storecod = Store.getStoreCode()
    url = "https://www.externallink.com/pay/payment.asp?codtienda=%s&numcompra=%s&mount=" % (storecod, donation.order_id)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

on urls.py

```
url(r'^events/(\d+)/$', views.callDonation, name="call_donation")
```

But getting

```
Reverse for 'call_donation' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'event': 4L}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['events/(\\d+)/$']
```

I'm lost on what should I change to make it work

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify keyword name in `urlpatterns`, like this:

```
url(r'^events/(?P<event_id>\d+)/$', views.callDonation, name="call_donation")
```

Also you have to make sure, that you pass correct keyword name in template (e.g. `event_id` instead of `event`).